# How can I filter max value in a group and min value in another group?

Tags: r, select, filter, dbplyr

I'm struggling with filtering options in R. I have this dataset:

```
patient_id    period     TREAT_CAT               Outcome
1            -3228 days pre-treatment                Pink
1            -3170 days pre-treatment                Pink
1              100 days post-treatment               Blue
1              200 days post-treatment               Pink
2            -2900 days pre-treatment                Blue
2                0 days post-treatment               Pink
2              100 days post-treatment               Pink

structure(list(patient_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
    period = structure(c(-3228, -3170, 100, 200, -2900, 
    0, 100), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    TREAT_CAT = structure(c( 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("pre-treatment", "post-treatment"), class = "factor"), 
    Outcome = c("Pink", "Pink", "Blue", "Pink", 
    "Blue", "Pink", "Pink"), row.names = c(19L, 26L, 24L, 3L, 7L, 29L, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to filter the closest "period" to 0 for the pre-treatment group and the farest "period" from 0 on the post-treatment group.

I've tried something like this

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(patient_id) %>% 
  filter((TREAT_CAT=="pre-treatment" & period == min(period)) | (TREAT_CAT=="post-treatment" & period == max(period))) %>% 
  filter(n() == 2)
```

But obviously it gaves me the farest from 0 from both periods. I've also tried with max(period) for both groups but it's not working because the max (period) it's only happening for the post-treatment group, resulting in 0 variables.

I would expect something like

```
patient_id    period     TREAT_CAT               Outcome
1            -3170 days pre-treatment                Pink
1              200 days post-treatment               Pink
2            -2900 days pre-treatment                Blue
2              100 days post-treatment               Pink
```

Could you please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post sample data with `dput(head(df, 15))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `pre-treatment` is always negative. That way, you *can* `slice_max()` on each group

```
df %>% 
  group_by(patient_id, TREAT_CAT) %>% 
  slice_max(period)

# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   patient_id, TREAT_CAT [4]
  patient_id period     TREAT_CAT      Outcome
       <dbl> <drtn>     <fct>          <chr>  
1          1 -3170 days pre-treatment  Pink   
2          1   200 days post-treatment Pink   
3          2 -2900 days pre-treatment  Blue   
4          2   100 days post-treatment Pink
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but didn't retain the "outcome" variable, how can I keep that in?

Comment: @Giorgia I realized that too - made an edit using the `slice_max()` instead